# set default value for form widget symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony-2.8

I want to set a default value for a form_widget with a variable twig
That's why I try with this code

```
{{ form_widget (form.etudiant, {'value': candidature.etudiant}) }}
```

Candidature.etudiant is an entity which I have access to it in this twig but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If etudiant is an entity so try :

```
{{ form_widget (form.etudiant, {'value': candidature.etudiant.name}) }}
```